# How can I make the pagination arrows work? Moving one page back or forward

Tags: javascript, html, function, deployment, navigation

I am currently creating a website where on this page, I want the user to have the option to navigate using my pagination arrows. I have currently set up 4 pages just for testing. Each page has its own href, as you can see in the code. The currently not used ones are the ones with href="#". So when the user is clicking on the "laquo;" button, I want the user to go one page back depending on what page the user is on. Same with the "raquo", just going forward.

This is my html file rendering one of the pages (they are the same, I have just added and removed the w3-grey depending on what page is being used): `<div class="w3-bar w3-border">`

```
{% extends "fagbase.html" %}

{% block title %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<head>
    <br><br>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='home.css') }}">
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="title">1P
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='math.png') }}" alt="Logo" class="logo">
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
<br>

<div class="w3-bar w3-border">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="/vgs/1P/1" id="page1" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple w3-grey">1</a>
    <a href="/vgs/1P/2" id="page2" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">2</a>
    <a href="/vgs/1P/3" id="page3" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">3</a>
    <a href="/vgs/1P/4" id="page4" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">...</a>
    <a href="#" id="oppgaver" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">Oppgaver</a>
    <a href="#" id="losningsforslag" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">Løsningsforslag</a>
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">&raquo;</a>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

---

I tried asking chatGPT (free version), and they gave a function, but nothing happend when I clicked the buttons.

Relevant code from chatGPT:

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-border">
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple" onclick="changePage('prev')">&laquo;</a>
        <a href="/vgs/1P/1" id="page1" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple w3-grey">1</a>
        <a href="/vgs/1P/2" id="page2" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">2</a>
        <a href="/vgs/1P/3" id="page3" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">3</a>
        <a href="/vgs/1P/4" id="page4" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">4</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">...</a>
        <a href="#" id="oppgaver" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">Oppgaver</a>
        <a href="#" id="losningsforslag" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple">Løsningsforslag</a>
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-ripple" onclick="changePage('next')">&raquo;</a>
</div>

<script>
        const pageLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.w3-bar-item');
        let currentPage = 0;  // Set the initial current page index

        function changePage(page) {
            // Update the current page based on the clicked button
            if (page === 'prev' && currentPage > 0) {
                currentPage--;
            } else if (page === 'next' && currentPage < pageLinks.length - 1) {
                currentPage++;
            }

            
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Hej! There's a few syntax issues with your code and without knowing a little bit more it's very difficult to say. I think the ChatGPT answer assumes something like an SPA page, but your code looks more like traditional server side rendering. What language/template is that `{% extends "fagbase.html" %}`? The main thing you will need is the current page number. Is that available from the URL or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

To make the pagination arrows work, you need to add some JavaScript code. The following code will do the trick:

```
function goToPage(pageNumber) {
 window.location.href = "page-" + pageNumber;
}

$(".laquo").click(function() {
  goToPage(parseInt($(this).attr("data-page"), 10) - 1);
});

$(".raquo").click(function() {
  goToPage(parseInt($(this).attr("data-page"), 10) + 1);
});
```

This code first defines a function called `goToPage()`. This function takes a page number as its argument and then sets the window's location to the page with that number.

The next two lines of code attach event listeners to the `.laquo` and `.raquo` elements. These event listeners call the `goToPage()` function with the current page number as their argument.

To use this code, you need to add it to the `<head>` section of your HTML file. You also need to add the following CSS code to style the pagination arrows:

```
.laquo, .raquo {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.laquo:hover, .raquo:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

This CSS code will make the pagination arrows change color when the user hovers over them.

Once you have added the JavaScript and CSS code, the pagination arrows should work as expected. When the user clicks on the `.laquo` arrow, they will be taken to the previous page. When the user clicks on the `.raquo` arrow, they will be taken to the next page.